# JFrame catch dispose event

Tags: java, jframe

I have a Java project.
I have a JFrame with a handler attached to it like so

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                this.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
```

But, on that frame I also have a close button (to make it more user friendly) and that "close" button calls the frame dispose method. Now, when I close the frame by clicking the little x button on the top right corner, the WindowListener is called. But the event doesn't fire when I invoke the dispose method.

should I Invoke some other method to close, so the WindowListener fires, or maybe implement another listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> on that frame i also have a close button (to make it more user friendly)

Check out the [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) solution to handle this. All you really need to do is add the "ExitAction" to your button, but you can use the whole approach if you want.

Answer (score 11):

You should take a look at the [WindowListener interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html).

[windowClosing()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)): Invoked when the **user attempts to close the window** from the window's system menu. (window **X** button)

[windowClosed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)): Invoked when a window has been closed as the result of calling **dispose** on the window.

So, `windowClosing()` is called **only** when the user clicks the **X** button of the window; `windowClosed()` is called when the `dispose()` event is invoked, so it is always invoked:

- if the user closes the frame using the windows **X** button
- if the frame is programatically closed by code

```
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            // your code
        }
    });
```

Source: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/closing-your-java-swing-application-when-user-presses-close-but

Comment: Beware: when using `windowClosed`, the window is already gone when the handler is called. Keep this in mind when you want to cleanup some resources (OpenGL context ...), as `windowClosed` may be already too late for this.

Comment: do you know why that information is not available here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch `dispose` reliably, no matter how it is called, you can override the `dispose` method. Usually you want to call `super.dispose()` and implement any custom handling before or after it as suitable for given task.

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo") {
            @Override
            public void dispose() {
                System.out.println("On dispose");
                super.dispose();
            }
        };
```